# Animate anchor link navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Wordpress website and have a navigation link which links to an anchored point at the bottom/footer of my page.

It links to #footer-anchor

HTML

```
<div id="footer-anchor"> ... </div>
```

It links properly, but I want the page to animate to the anchor point, right now it just 'pops' to the anchor point.

EDIT:  I am using Wordpress, so I can't hardcode the button in the html (I don't think I can anyway)

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/2603230

Comment: This is similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677035/jquery-scroll-to-element)

Comment: I am using Wordpress, so I don't have specific control on the button itself. All I can do in the link the url to #footer-anchor in the admin side (menu panel)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scrollTop` property.

```
$("#anchor").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#footer-anchor").scrollTop() }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: put into the <head> tags?

Comment: I am using Wordpress, so I don't have specific control on the button itself. All I can do in the link the url to #footer-anchor in the admin side (menu panel)

Comment: You will have to customize it a bit. Replace `#footer-anchor` in href with `javascript:;`. Assign an `id` to anchor and add the code snippet in js file.

Comment: i'm confused as to what you mean in your comment. I have an #id on the div called #footer-anchor. and in the menu admin panel it says URL: #footer-anchor instead of a www link